# how to access pods from host?

Tags: kubernetes, colima

I'm running colima with kubernetes like:
`colima start --kuberenetes`

I created a few running pods, and I want to see access the through the browsers.
But I don't know what is the colima IP (or kubernetes node IP).

help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the nodeIp so:

```
kubectl get node

NAME       STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
nodeName   Ready    <none>   15h   v1.26.0
```

Then with the nodeName:

```
kubectl describe node nodeName
```

That gives you a descrition of the node and you should look for this section:

```
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  10.165.39.165
  Hostname:    master
```

Ping it to verify the network.

Find your host file on Mac and make an entry like:

```
10.165.39.165 test.local
```

This let you access the cluster with a domain name.

Ping it to verify.

You can not access from outside the cluster a ClusterIp.
To access your pod you  have several possibilities.

1. if your service is type ClusterIp, you can create a temporary connection from your host with a port forward.

```
kubectl port-forward svc/yourservicename localport:podport
```

2. (i would raccomend this) create a service type: NodePort

Then

```
kubectl get svc -o wide
```

Shows you the NodePort: between(30000-32000).

You can access now the Pod by: test.local:nodePort or Ipaddress:NodePort.

Note: If you deployed in a namespace other than default, add -n yournamespace in the kubectl commands.

Update:

if you want to start colima with an ipAddress, first find one of your local network which is available.

Your network setting you can get with:

```
ifconfig
```

find the network. Should be the same of that of your Internet router.

Look for the subnet. Most likely 255.255.255.0.

The value to pass then:

```
  --network-address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24
```

In case the subnet is 255.255.0.0 then /16. But i dont think, if you are connect from home. Inside a company however this is possible.

Again check with ping and follow the steps from begining to verify the kubernetes node configuration.

Comment: appreciated the response!

I needed to run colima with: `colima start --network-address`

can you please add this to your answer, so Ill mark it as resolved

Comment: I did an update, hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks would be nice if you upvote too.

Comment: Thank you! One minor thing though, current colima (`0.5.2`) does not support any arguments to `start --network-address`. So we're supposed to use the auto one, can be seen with `colima status`.